# Работа с generics с неизвестными типами

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Нужно работать со списком - создавать и заполнять. Тип списка такой.

```
List<Animal<T>>;
```

Вместо T имеется объект valueType типа Type, который передали извне. Конструируем итоговый тип.

```
var animalGenType= typeof(Animal<>).MakeGenericType(valueType);
var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(animalGenType);
```

Далее мы можем создать объекты этих типов

```
var list = Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
var animal= Activator.CreateInstance(animalGenType);
```

Но как с этим работать? Ведь созданные объекты имеют тип Object и мы не можем привести их к нужному типу (у нас нет T). А без этого как заполнять animal и потом добавлять его в list

UPD: добавил пример метода. Он принимает уже имеющийся Type targetPetType, так что T пихать некуда.

```
public object ParsePets(IEnumerable<string> lines, Type targetPetType){
    var animalGenType= typeof(Animal<>).MakeGenericType(valueType);
    var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(animalGenType);

    var result = Activator.CreateInstance(listType);         

    foreach(var line in lines){             
       var pet= Activator.CreateInstance(animalGenType);   
       //заполняем pet данными из line
       ...
       // добавляем в список
       ...      
    }                                       
    return result;  
}
```

Выходит только рефлексия?

Comment: если при создании объекта используется рефлексия, то и при изменении объекта она вполне может использоваться

Comment: а зачем вы вообще тут рефлексию используете а не обычный конструктор?

Comment: @Grundy а как тут использовать обычный конструктор?

Comment: например вот так :-) `var l = new List<Animal<T>>()`

Comment: @Grundy но у нас нет сигнатуры T. Вместо него нам передали typeof(T) и мы имеем Type type

Comment: стоит добавить больше информации в вопрос :-) ну и в любом случае, смотри мой первый комментарий - используй рефлексию для добавления

Comment: стоит добавить в вопрос пример функции, внутри которой выполняются данные действия, что она принимает и что возвращает и какие действия внутри ожидаются

Comment: @Grundy добавил пример. Про рефлексию понятно, но неужели нет чего побыстрее или более типизировано?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41394/discussion-between-grundy-and-vitidev).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создайте обобщенную функцию:

```
static IList<Animal<T>> ParsePetsImpl<T>(IEnumerable<string> lines) {
  // реализация
  // тут у нас есть тип T
}
```

Теперь эту функцию можно вызвать через рефлексию:

```
public object ParsePets(IEnumerable<string> lines, Type targetPetType) {
  var method = GetType().GetMethod("ParsePetsImpl", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
  return method.MakeGenericMethod(targetPetType).Invoke(null, new object[] { lines });
}
```

Если предполагается такие вызовы делать часто - то лучше динамически скомпилировать обертку:

```
private static Func<IEnumerable<string>, object> MakeParsePetsImpl(Type targetPetType) {
  var method = GetType().GetMethod("ParsePetsImpl", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic).MakeGenericMethod(targetPetType);
  var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IEnumerable<string>));
  var body = Expression.Call(method, null, p);
  return Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerable<string>, object>>(body, p).Compile();
}
private static ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Func<IEnumerable<string>, object>> parsePetsImpls = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Func<IEnumerable<string>, object>>();
public object ParsePets(IEnumerable<string> lines, Type targetPetType) {
   return parsePetsImpls.GetOrAdd(targetPetType, MakeParsePetsImpl)(lines);
}
```

Comment: можно тогда и сам _ParsePetsImpl_ собрать

Comment: @Grundy это будет усложнение. При всей красоте `Expression` код "на нем" получается куда менее красивым чем код на C#.

Comment: ну тут еще зависит от конкретного кода, возможно там те же две строчки создания и добавления и они не так уж и сильно будут отличаться

Comment: Вот что значит опыт. А у меня даже мысли не возникло просто написать типизированный Т метод и работать уже с генерик методом, а не  с самими объектами. Или про Expression вызов метода - везде примеры создания самой фабрики объектов средствами Expression.

Answer (score 3):

Скастить к System.Collection.IList. Далее использовать метод Add(object item).

```
var result = Activator.CreateInstance(listType);         

var list = (System.Collections.IList)result;

foreach(var line in lines){             
   var pet= Activator.CreateInstance(animalGenType);   
   //заполняем pet данными из line
   ...
   // добавляем в список
   list.Add(pet);
}                                       
return result;
```

Comment: Ну для списка есть интерфейс такой. А для других классов нет. Я ж не могу pet скастить к Animal<>

Comment: @vitidev Сделать IAnimal, если необходимо.