# Получить тип класса по его имени

Tags: c#, рефлексия

Как получить тип класса по его имени?

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main<T>(string[] args)
    {
        string className = "MyClass";
        var myClassType = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(className));

        var res = method<myClassType>();
    }

    public static List<T> method<T>()
    {
        return new List<T>();
    }
}
public class MyClass
{
    public string anyString { get; set; }
    public int anyInt { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: что дальше ты хочешь делать с этим списком? как использовать?

Comment: Дело не в списке, это просто пример, мне нужно получить тип класса по строковому имени

Comment: _мне нужно получить тип класса по строковому имени_ - ты его уже получаешь `Type.GetType(className)`

Comment: `var myClassType` - тут var = object.

Comment: @Grundy, ну он же написал пример - всё вполне понятно. Только первый пример был лучше.. возможно.

Comment: в `GetType()` передавайте полное квалифицированное имя класса с простраством имён

Comment: ` string className = "MyClass";
            string namespaceName = "ConsoleApplication17";
            var myClassType = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(namespaceName + "." + className));

            var res = method<myClassType>();`

Comment: Не работает т.к. myClassType - object а не класс

Comment: @Alex, если начал использовать рефлексию, то без нее уже никуда. Все только через нее надо.

Comment: Судя по вопросу вы хотите получить объект класса по наименованию типа, а не тип класса по его имени

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Работа с generics с неизвестными типами](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536812/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-generics-%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Answer (score 2):

Красивым способом это не сделать, нужно использовать reflection и [MakeGenericMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod.aspx):

```
string className = "ConsoleApplication1.MyClass";
var myClassType = Type.GetType(className);

var method = typeof(Program).GetMethod("method", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(myClassType);

// вернет список нужного типа - List<MyClass>
dynamic list = genericMethod.Invoke(null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Activator` отдаст Вам ссылку типа `object` на созданный объект класса по полному квалифицированному имени класса:

```
Type type = Type.GetType("ConsoleApplication17.MyClass");

object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Если Вы хотите обращаться к методам и полям объекта класса напрямую, то Вам нужно будет в явном виде указать конкретный тип. Для этого можно использовать, например, безопасное приведение типа:

```
var propertyValue = (instance as MyClass)?.anyInt;
```

Если Вы не хотите явно указывать тип в коде, то можете воспользоваться механизмом динамической типизации:

```
try
{
     dynamic dynamicInstance = instance;
     var propertyValue = dynamicInstance.anyInt
}
catch(RuntimeBinderException ex)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Wrong type specified: " + ex.Message);
}
```

Обратите внимание на обработку `RuntimeBinderException`.

Comment: в примере кода написано же что мне нужно. Нужно получить сам класс, чтобы его использовать как тип, методов у него нет!

Comment: `myClassType` - это ссылка на объект типа `object`. А "сам класс", как Вы его называете - это литерал. Если хотите создать коллекцию `List<MyClass>`, но при этом нигде в коде не использовать литерал имени класса - создайте коллекцию `List<dynamic>`, либо `List<object>`. Последнее предпочтительнее.

Comment: @ klutch1991, динамический объект мне не подходит, т.к. далее по коду необходим конкретный класс, имя которого получаю на клиенте

Comment: Update<T>(id), where T : class (маппинг на таблицу)

Comment: Как я понимаю, на c# это невозможно?

Comment: Из `String` получить ссылку на конкретный тип не получится. Можете написать какой-то свой `TypeMapHelper`, который будет преобразовывать Ваш объект в конкретный тип в зависимости от переданного в него `String`.  Но минус в том что при добавлении новых типов придётся вносить поправки в код Helper'a. Если хотите, могу привести в ответе примерный код такого класса.

Comment: Да, покажите плиз

Comment: Пардон, в случае, если писать какой-то Helper, то в generic  в любом случае нужно передать конкретный тип. В общем-то да, то, что Вы хотите, сделать на C# не получится.

Comment: Знаю на JS можно вызвать функцию по её строковому названию (eval()), на c# видимо нет

Comment: Если Вы используете EF, то без конкретных типов не обойтись.

Comment: @ klutch1991, всё же можно увидеть для общего развития?

Comment: По большому счёту логика сведётся к тому же безопасному приведению типа: `public static T CastToType<T>(object o) where T : class { return o as T; }`

Answer (score -2):

Для получения типа по имени нужно дописывать пространство имен, а лучше использовать полное имя с указанием имени сборки.

Получить тип лучше из сборки. Предварительно её загрузив. Для .Net Core это выглядит так

```
static Assembly LoadAssembly(string fileName)
    {

        var Dir = AppContext.BaseDirectory;
        string path = Path.Combine(Dir, fileName);
        Assembly assembly = null;
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            try
            {
                var asm = System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.GetAssemblyName(path);
                assembly = Assembly.Load(asm);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                assembly = System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(path);
            }
        }
        return assembly;

    }
```

Ну а из сборки можешь получить и тип используя GetType

Посмотри здесь [.Net Core, AppDomain, WCF, RPC маршалинг по Tcp/Ip свой велосипед](https://habrahabr.ru/post/323096/)

Там и поиск типа, методов с параметрами по умолчанию, параметрами массивами, Дженерик методами, методов расширений в том числе Linq, делегатов, объектов поддерживающие IDynamicMetaObjectProvider (DynamicObject,ExpandoObject,JObject).
 В том числе поиск дженерик метода с автовыводм типа по параметрам

Например там реализован динамический вызов дженерик метода

```
// Test Generic Method с параметрами по умолчанию 
    //public string GenericMethodWithDefaulParam<K, V>(Dictionary<K, V> param1, K param2, int param3 = 4, string param4 = "Test")
    var @Int32 = wrap.GetType("System.Int32");
    resGM = TO.GenericMethodWithDefaulParam(dict, 99);
    Console.WriteLine("Вызов дженерик метода с автовыводом  типов " + resGM);

    resGM = TO.GenericMethodWithDefaulParam(pp(@Int32, "System.String"), dict, 99);
    Console.WriteLine("Вызов дженерик метода с аргументами типов " + resGM);



    // Test Generic Method с параметрами массивом
    // public string GenericMethodWithParams<K, V>(Dictionary<K, V> param1, K param2, params string[] args)

    resGM = TO.GenericMethodWithParams(dict, 99, "First", "Second");
    Console.WriteLine("Вызов дженерик метода с автовыводом  типов " + resGM);
```

Где TO это динамик вызывающий метод по Tcp/IP, но его можно приязать к типу и вызвать методы локально. 
Просто для поиска метода из-за перегрузок, дефолтных параметрах, параметрах массивов не всегда простая задача

Для обычного .Net поиск сборки выглядит так.
Сразу прошу прощения за Руслиш.

```
 private static Type НайтиТип(string type)
        {

            Type result = Type.GetType(type, false);

            if (result != null)
            {

                return result;
            }

            foreach (System.Reflection.Assembly tmpAasembly in
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
            {
                result = tmpAasembly.GetType(type);
                if (result != null)
                {
                    return result;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }



    public object ПолучитьТипИзСборки(string type, string путь)
            {
                var result = НайтиТип(type);
                if (result != null)
                    return new AutoWrap(result);

                string ошибка;
                string path;
                System.Reflection.Assembly assembly;
                if (File.Exists(путь))
                    assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(путь);
                else
                { 
                    path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(string).Assembly.Location), путь);
                if (File.Exists(path))
                {

                    var ИмяСборки = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(path).FullName;
                    assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(ИмяСборки);
                }
                else
                {
                    ошибка = " Не найден файл " + путь + " или  " + path;
                    MessageBox.Show(ошибка);
                    throw new COMException(ошибка);

                }
                }

                result = assembly.GetType(type);
                if (result != null)
                {

                    return new AutoWrap(result);
                }

                 ошибка = " неверный тип " + type + " в сборке " + assembly.Location;
                MessageBox.Show(ошибка);
                throw new COMException(ошибка);
                //    return null;
            }
```

Comment: причем тут .net core? GetType автор уже использует.

Comment: Я дал ответ и для .Net Core и для обычного .Net

Comment: И как твой ответ помогает в вопросе автора? GetType он уже вызывал в самом вопросе.

Comment: Есть разница между Assembly.GetType и Type.GetType

Comment: И как эта разница поможет в вопросе автора?

Comment: Ну вопервых у него тип без пространства имен, а получить тип он может из других сборок где нужно указывать полное имя

Comment: Но у него ведь проблема не с получением типа, а с дальнейшим его использованием. Посмотри пример: он пытается использовать его как generic параметр.

Comment: Понял. Прошу прощения. Конечно MakeGenericMethod, но по ссылке как раз есть поиск дженерик метода с выводом типа по параметрм и указанием типа

Comment: По ссылке, это по ссылке. Получается в вопросе полезна только ссылка, а ответы состоящие только из ссылок - не приветствуются. Стоит убрать из ответа все лишнее, а нужное добавить непосредственно в ответ.

Comment: Ну может кому и пригодится. А поиск там замороченный. например  // public string GenericMethodWithParams<K, V>(Dictionary<K, V> param1, K param2, params string[] args)

        resGM = TO.GenericMethodWithParams(dict, 99, "First", "Second"); ГДЕ TO это dynamic