# Как сделать cast с помощью переменной типа Type?

Tags: c#

Допустим где-то ранее по коду я сохранил тип переменной

```
Type type = typeof(Int32);
```

Теперь имея переменную `value` типа `object` мне нужно сделать cast c помощью моей `type` как то так,

```
var i = (type)value;
```

но так не работает. Что можно сделать?

UPD
На всякий случай, так тоже не работает

```
var i = (type)Convert.ChangeType(value, type);
```

**UPD2**: *по просьбе Pavel Mayorov* добавляю в вопрос свой комментарий:

"...идея была такая: есть базовый абстрактный класс со свойством `Object Value` и со свойством `Type ValueType`. Конкретный класс унаследовал этот абстрактный, назначал бы нужный тип свойству `ValueType`, а свойству `Value` собственно значимую величину. Далее при работе с коллекцией типов унаследованных от абстр.класса, можно было бы извлекать значение `Value` нужного типа получая для этого тип из `ValueType`.".

Comment: `Convert.ChangeType()`?

Comment: @arrowd Сейчас обновлю вопрос.

Comment: В чем смысл? Если нужна переменная типа `int`, то кастуйте напрямую в `int`.

Comment: `int i = (type)Convert.ChangeType(value, type);` зачем первый (type) ? там  же (int) тогда должен. или тип i должен быть другим.

Comment: @Raider смысл есть.

Comment: @Чад `Convert.ChangeType()` возвращает `object`

Comment: @Bulson именно.

Comment: Вопрос не понятен, вы вот пишете `int i = ...`, т.е. еще *до* запуска программы знаете, что там будет `int`, вот и укажите тогда `(int)`

Comment: @АндрейNOP я сейчас исправлю на `var`, чтоб вы не попадались в ловушку простого решения.

Comment: @Bulson, ок, исправите. Но! Вы забываете, что `var` - это та же самая статическая типизация и тип будет определен на *этапе компиляции* и будет определен он как `object`. А `Convert.ChangeType` как раз и возвращает `object`

Comment: @АндрейNOP когда вы делаете так `var i = (int)value;` вы знаете, что за `var` прячется `int`. Теперь берем `var i = (type)value;` мне надо получить `type i`.

Comment: Не, это не я знаю, что за `var` прячется `int`, это компилятор выясняет еще на этапе компиляции и создает переменную типа `int` изначально. Нельзя создать переменную типа не зная этот тип на этапе компиляции!

Comment: Решал такую же проблему. Привести к T невозможно, ведь его нет. Зато можно вызвать generic метод с <T> через рефлексию или еще как.

Comment: @vitidev да я уже это осознал.

Comment: скажите пжалста, правильно ли я понял задачу: у вас *на входе* именно переменная значащего (но неизвестно, какого именно) типа, а *на выходе* надо получить свою переменную того же (входного) значащего типа, но с неким своим значением? Ни *на входе*, ни *на выходе* не должно быть ссылочного/объектного/упакованного типа?

Comment: вот если что мой вопрос по точно такой же проблеме http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536812/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-generics-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8/

Comment: @Alias идея была такая: есть базовый абстрактный класс со свойством `Object Value` и со свойством `Type ValueType`. Конкретный класс унаследовал этот абстрактный, назначал бы нужный тип свойству `ValueType`, а свойству `Value` собственно значимую величину. Далее при работе с коллекцией типов унаследованных от абстр.класса, можно было бы извлекать значение `Value` нужного типа получая для этого тип из `ValueType`.

Comment: @Bulson пожалуйста, перенесите ваш последний комментарий в вопрос

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проведем небольшой тест

Функция для каста:

```
object CastTo<T>(object inp)
{
    return Convert.ChangeType(inp, typeof(T));  
}
```

Сам тест:

```
void Main()
{
    double d = 99.19;
    Console.WriteLine(d.GetType().Name);

    var intVal = CastTo<int>(d);
    Console.WriteLine(intVal.GetType().Name);   

    Console.WriteLine(d);       
    Console.WriteLine(intVal);      
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
Double
Int32
99.19
99
```

**UPD**

Если у вас под рукой нет Generic параметра, но вам нужно вызвать Generic метод, то вы можете сделать это через dynamic  вот так:

```
void Main()
{
    object value = 100; 
    CallGenericMethod(value);
}

public void CallGenericMethod(object inp)
{
    GenericMethod((dynamic)inp);
}

public T GenericMethod<T>(T inp) 
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Generic called! Parameter type {typeof(T).Name}, input type {inp.GetType().Name}");
    return inp;
}
```

Вывод:

```
Generic called! Parameter type Int32, input type Int32
```

Comment: Вы же возвращаете опять `object` из `CastTo<T>()`?! Т.е. от чего ушли к тому же и вернулись?

Comment: @Bulson не совсем, был boxed double, стал boxed int

Comment: @Bulson или я просто не понял, что вам нужно сделать

Comment: Мне не тип в боксе поменять или привести, а вернуть переменную к типу, который я заблаговременно сохранил ранее.

Comment: Можно сделать `(T)Convert.ChangeType(inp, typeof(T));` и возвращаемый тип `T`

Comment: @АндрейNOP разве?

Comment: @АндрейNOP я так не сделал, так как, насколько я понял, у автора вопроса нет генерик параметра под рукой. Я тест написал просто по сути проверить `Convert.ChangeType(inp, typeof(T));`

Comment: @tym32167, я понял. А вот вопрос я теперь уже получается не понимаю. Как можно объявить переменную типа, которой ты не знаешь? Можно только объявить переменную более общего типа (`object` в самом терминальном случае). А если уж мы знаем тип, то просто явно кастуем `(int)o`

Comment: @Bulson добавил инфу, как вызвать обобщенный метод. Но вообще да, не понятно, что вам надо сделать.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. Я понял, что придется работать через `dynamic`.

Comment: Ага, фишка в том, что результат вызова этого метода надо записать в переменную, а эту переменную надо объявить, но мы не знаем тип, поэтому можем объявить только переменную только более общего типа (`object`). В итоге мы возвращаемся к тому, от чего начали... Единственный выход - работать с `dynamic`, что по сути тот же `object`, но на нем проще вызывать методы, не нужно использовать рефлексию явно

Comment: Зы. вместо `GenericMethod<T>` метод можно просто кастовать к `dynamic`: `var a = (dynamic)b;` или `dynamic a = b;`

Comment: @АндрейNOP Я написал Generic метод на случай, если автору надо вызвать метод с обобщением, а у него есть только `object value` и её тип `Type type`. То есть по сути вызов метода - это то, что я и показать то хотел.

Comment: Зачем отдельная функция Proc?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Вы меня сегодня проверяете :) Она осталась когда я собирал пример из своих исходников. В принципе не нужна. Убрал, чтобы не путать никого.

Answer (score 4):

Компилятор не может работать с переменной неизвестного типа. У любой переменной должен быть известный на этапе компиляции тип данных.

Но вам и не нужна переменная неизвестного типа: требуемый тип переменной определяется тем, как с ней предполагается работать. И его всегда можно определить.

---

Как видно из ваших уточнений, вам нужно создать не просто переменную - а свойство в базовом классе. Эта задача решается проще чем вы думаете: достаточно сделать абстрактное свойство типа `object`.

```
abstract class Foo
{
    public abstract Type ValueType { get; }
    public abstract object UntypedValue { get; set; }
}
```

Нет никакой необходимости как-то дополнительно указывать что тип свойства `UntypedValue` - на самом деле `ValueType` (разве что можно написать об этом в комментарии).

Ну а в производных классах просто перегружаем `UntypedValue`, делая так чтобы это свойство работало так как нам надо:

```
class Foo<T> : Foo
{
    public override Type ValueType => typeof(T);
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public override object UntypedValue 
    {
        get { return Value; }
        set { Value = (T)value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, за толковый ответ.